# import script tag into react app (undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is a react.js app, the code below works on index.html but not on  JSX, I'll need to store information from the callback that would be easier if I can make that script tag works, I tried importing the src file using two third-party libraries without success

```
    <ScriptTag type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://cdn.paddle.com/paddle/paddle.js" />

    <Script
      url="https://cdn.paddle.com/paddle/paddle.js"
      onCreate={this.handleScriptCreate.bind(this)}
      onError={this.handleScriptError.bind(this)}
      onLoad={this.handleScriptLoad.bind(this)}
    />
```

> 'Paddle' is not defined  no-undef

This is HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Paddle.Setup({
    vendor: 123456,
     completeDetails: true
  });
</script>
```

I understand that I didn't import `Paddle` but I am not sure how to do it. On plain HTML it automatically import the `paddle.js`. Why is not loading on JSX?

```
 checkout() {
    console.log('checkout');
    Paddle.Setup({
      vendor: 49773,
      completeDetails: true
    });
    Paddle.Checkout.open({
      product: 12345,
      email: "jane@paddle.com",
      passthrough: 1939284,
      successCallback: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert('Thanks for your purchase.');
      },
      closeCallback: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert('Your purchase has been cancelled, we hope to see you again soon!');
      }
    });
  }
```

https://paddle.com/docs/paddle-checkout-web/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module cannot be used in JSX even if script tag imported correctly.